# How to use FB.api('/me/picture') to get profile image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is a very silly question. I'm a beginner with facebook Javascript SDK.
So I'm trying to make a the user's profile image to show 
I used this code

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {      
    document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture" />';
});
```

which worked fine, but I'm trying to understand how to use `FB.api('/me/picture')` to show the image.

Answer (score 15):

`/me/picture` (or `/{user id}/picture`) returns an HTTP 301 redirect to the image location so you can embed it directly into an `<img src...`

If you want to retrieve the URL and use it yourself you need to specifically request it as a field, via :

```
 /{user id}?fields=picture
```

or

```
 /me/?fields=picture
```

You can include other fields too, but I'm assuming you just want the photo right now.

Comment: does `/me/picture` return a url (or an object)? You said that you can embed it directly into an `<img src` as well, so Whats the difference between `/me/picture` and ` /{user id}?fields=picture`?

Comment: `/me/picture` returns a HTTP 301 redirect to the image, `?fields=picture` returns the URL as a field of the JSON response

Comment: Need to? it's a feature of the API to support use of of the API response directly in an `<img/>` tag - most people probably won't do that and will fetch the image URLs and use those directly

Comment: @lgy: I know it has been a while. I am wondering whether you can show me an example how to use "/me/?fields=picture". Thanks.

Comment: Take the URL from response and put it into an img tag directly - the exact steps needed to do that very much depend on how your app works and what language you're using - you can see the response format by making API calls using the Graph API Explorer tool here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 9):

You can get specific sizes of the profile pic as well:

```
FB.api("/me/picture?width=180&height=180",  function(response) {

        console.log(response.data.url);

});
```

See the [Facebook documentation to see what different picture sizes you can get](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/).

And a complete demo with login at: [Get Facebook Profile Picture with Javascript SDK](http://www.jensbits.com/2013/04/04/get-facebook-profile-picture-with-javascript-sdk/)

Comment: Type is handy if you don't want to have to specify a precise size and just want a fuzzy value like small, normal, large:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dpicture.type(normal)&version=

Answer (score 1):

This is sure shot, Proved to be working with facebook graph api 2.5.
This is the sample HTML Please see the changes I have made in FB.api() function.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

    <!--
      Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
      the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
      the FB.login() function when clicked.
    -->
    <img src="" id="profileImage"/>

    <div id="status">
    </div>

    </body>
    <script>

        // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
        function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            console.log('statusChangeCallback');
            console.log(response);
            // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
            // app know the current login status of the person.
            // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
            // for FB.getLoginStatus().
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                testAPI();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                        'into this app.';
            } else {
                // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
                // they are logged into this app or not.
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                        'into Facebook.';
            }
        }

        // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
        // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
        // code below.
        function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
                cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                                    // the session
                xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
            });

            // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
            //FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
            // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
            // the callback you provide.  They can be:
            //
            // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
            // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
            // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
            //    your app or not.
            //
            // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });

        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
        // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
        function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.id);
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.email);
                var im = document.getElementById("profileImage").setAttribute("src", "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture?type=normal");
                document.getElementById('username').innerHTML =response.name;
            });
        }

    </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the Facebook profile picture All sizes

**Profile Picture Sizes**

value = 
`24`
`32`
`40`
`50`
`60`
`74`
`80`
`86`
`100`
`111`
`120`
`130`
`148`
`160`
`200`
`240`
`320`
`480`
`720`
`960`
`1440`

**CURL**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/me?fields=picture.width(value).height(2000)&access_token={}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FB.api('/me/picture')` will return a [redirect](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) to the image URL, so it'll be of no use for you:
[image]
The way you are using is valid as mentioned in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) (Reading section). Maybe [this](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=65075) is related but I don't know if it's totally valid or not.

Comment: that's interesting. I wonder what's the use for  fb.api('me/picture')?  Thank you very much for reply

Comment: @user573451: well, I guess the api exists for server-side purposes `$facebook->api('/me/picture');`, like saving the raw image (maybe?) or something...but as far as client-side is your concern, I don't think of any use for it and you are already using the correct way. :-)