# Retrieving Facebook Profile Picture URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using satellizer for authentication in a MEAN app. After auth is complete i want to get the profile picture of the user. The following is my code.

**Angular Controller**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('nayakans07')
        .controller('RegisterController', registerController);

    function registerController ($scope, $auth) {

        $scope.authenticate = function (provider) {
            $auth.authenticate(provider)
                .then(function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                }, authErrorHandler);
        };

        function authErrorHandler (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

})();
```

**Node.js Route Handler**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var request = require('request');
    var qs = require('querystring');
    var tokenHelper = require('../helpers/tokenHelper.js');
    var config = require('../config/configuration.js');
    var Member = require('../models/memberModel.js');

    module.exports = function (req, res) {
        var accessTokenUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
        var grapApiProfileUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me';
        var graphApiProfileImageUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?width=250&json=true';

        var params = {
            client_id: req.body.clientId,
            redirect_uri: req.body.redirectUri,
            code: req.body.code,
            client_secret: config.FACEBOOK_SECRET
        };

        request.get({
            url: accessTokenUrl,
            qs: params
        }, function (err, response, accessToken) {
            accessToken = qs.parse(accessToken);
            request.get({
                url: grapApiProfileUrl,
                qs: accessToken,
                json: true
            }, function (err, response, profile) {
                console.log(profile);
                Member.findOne({
                    facebookId: profile.id
                }, function (err, existingMember) {
                    if (existingMember) {
                        return res.status(200).send({
                            user: existingMember,
                            token: tokenHelper.createToken(existingMember, req, res)
                        });
                    } else {
                        request.get({
                            url: graphApiProfileImageUrl,
                            qs: accessToken,
                        }, function (err, response, profileImage) {
                            console.log(profileImage);
                            var fbData = {
                                facebookId: profile.id,
                                fullName: profile.name,
                                email: profile.email,
                                profileImage: profileImage
                            };
                            return res.status(200).send(fbData);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    };


})();
```

After i get the access token from facebook i call the `https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?width=250&json=true` endpoint with the access token to get the profile pic link. In the [Facebook's API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpicture%3Fwidth%3D250%26json%3Dtrue%26redirect%3Dtrue&version=v2.4) calling the same endpoint with the token i get the profile image url but when i call it from node.js endpoint handler i get some binary like data. part of the response is here.

```
����JFIF���Photoshop 3.08BIM�gtc2XjTON-90Jqu9JFj83(bFBMD01000ac0030000b909000069110000fe120000dc14000069190000c02400002326000029280000872a0000fd3e0000��ICC_PROF
```

How can i get the URL for the profile image instead of this response.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is still the case on the version of the API that you're using, but it used to cause a 301 redirect to the image if not passed the correct parameter (despite what their API Explorer suggests...) You can check your browser's network monitoring to verify this.

There are various sources for this, including the Official Facebook Graph-API documentation, which states:

> By default this edge will return a 302 redirect to the picture image. To get access to the data about the picture, please include redirect=false in your query.

(Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/#Reading )

Along with some (older, but similar) SO answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881978/624590

You have a couple options. One is to add the `redirect=false` query param (per the Facebook documentation, above).

Another option is explicitly asking for the URL by adding an additional query param, `&fields=url` (the answer I linked to above suggests `&fields=picture`, but as far as I can tell, that's out of date). If you need the height and width in the response, just add those to the query: `&fields=url,height,width`. In my experience with the Facebook API, explicitly asking for fields tends to be a more reliable way to go.