# Facebook graph how to set parameters for picture?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get user picture URL, but instead i get image download. In facebook developer guide It says to set redirect parameter to 0 but i don't know how to set parameters in graph, i tried it in JavaScript to but i still get picture downloaded not the URL any example, how to set parameters?

Here is what i tried:

```
/me?fields=id,name,picture?redirect=0
```

It returns syntax error.

The simple request returns image download

```
me?fields=id,name,picture
```

This is the example result:

```
"picture": {
    "data": {
      "height": 50,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=3008732859171455&height=50&width=50&ext=1587125741&hash=AeSgpchLcdbLL1Mt",
      "width": 50
    }
  }
```

Comment: _“This is the example result:”_ - and what is the problem with that? You got an image URL in there, so take it and use it for whatever you want now. Who is actually “downloading” anything here?

Comment: When i open the link it automaticaly downloads the image. I cant mount it to React <Image> component.

Comment: The URL put into `<img src="...">` in a normal HTML document, works fine. If you have trouble processing it in React - then you might need to start looking into it from that side of things, but it isn’t really an API issue to begin with then IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/me/picture` would be the correct endpoint, or `/me/picture?redirect=false` if you do not want to redirect.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Comment: I get url but if you try to open it. It downloads the image.
{
  "data": {
    "height": 50,
    "is_silhouette": false,
    "url": "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=3008732859171455&height=50&width=50&ext=1587135290&hash=AeRHmrBiuf1Y-VHp",
    "width": 50
  }
}

Comment: it may be a bug, or it may have changed, but that was the (old) way, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674960/how-to-use-fb-api-me-picture-to-get-profile-image - you can also just use the direct link though after calling the api to get the picture as json.